# In Ninject, how do I set all bindings with a specific base interface to singleton

Tags: ninject, automapper

I'm trying to figure out how to tell ninject to set the scope all bindings with a specific base type. I think the below is close, but it doesn't work:

```
var scanner = new AssemblyScanner();
scanner.FromCallingAssembly();
scanner.BindWith<DefaultBindingGenerator>();
kernel.Scan(scanner);

//maps.Count is always 0 :-(
var maps = kernel.GetBindings(typeof(IMapper<,>));
foreach (var map in maps)
{
    map.ScopeCallback = StandardScopeCallbacks.Singleton;
}
```

One of the objects I want to be singleton:

```
public interface ILoanApplicationModelToViewMapper : IMapper<LoanApplication, LoanApplicationViewModel>
{
}

public class LoanApplicationModelToViewMapper : Mapper<LoanApplication, LoanApplicationViewModel>, ILoanApplicationModelToViewMapper
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assembly scanner has some magic that ended up working

```
        var scanner = new AssemblyScanner();
        scanner.WhereTypeIsNotInNamespace("Loan.Service.Storage.Context");
        scanner.WhereTypeIsNotInNamespace("Loan.Service.Mappers");
        scanner.FromCallingAssembly();
        scanner.BindWith<DefaultBindingGenerator>();
        kernel.Scan(scanner);

        var mapScanner = new AssemblyScanner();
        mapScanner.FromCallingAssembly();
        mapScanner.WhereTypeIsInNamespace("Loan.Service.Mappers");
        mapScanner.BindWith<DefaultBindingGenerator>();
        mapScanner.InSingletonScope();
        kernel.Scan(mapScanner);
```